# GmailApp getAliases doesn't include the account's main email address

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

[`GmailApp` `getAliases`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getAliases()) is useful to get the list of aliases / imported accounts, it works.

But the returned list does not include the account's main email address.

**How to get the account's main email address from `GmailApp`?** (without hardcoding it in a Google Apps script)

[image]

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, for example, is this script of `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` the direction you expect? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser())

Comment: This is the answer, thanks @Tanaike, can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I would like to propose the following script.

```
const emailAddress = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```

Reference:

- [getActiveUser() of Class Session](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser())